# Is getChildren() of ContentProvider called before treeExpanded() of ITreeViewerListener?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, treeviewer

I want to fetch data if a specific element of a tree is expanded.

```
public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent event) {  
   Object element = event.getElement();
   if (element instanceof MyClass) {
      fetch.......
   }
}
```

The problem is that the content provider seems to trigger `getChildren()` before the treeExpanded()-method so I get a `NullPointerException` everytime I expand the element because the content provider tries to use the data which is never fetched. How can i solve this properly?

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should not depend on the order in which `getChildren()` and `treeExpanded()` is called. This is an implementation detail of the `TreeViewer` and may change in the future.

Fetch the elements to be shown in `getChildren()` or `inputChanged()` of the content provider.

If your fetch operation takes too long to be run in the UI thread, run it in a background thread and return a placeholder element that is replaced, once the fetch operation finishes. For an example, see the `DeferredTreeContentManager` of `org.eclipse.ui`.

Alternatively you can see if the JFace `DeferredContentProvider` fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the content provider `getChildren` is called before the `treeExpanded` event is fired. You cannot use this event to populate the tree.

If you want to delay getting parts of the tree perhaps you should be looking at a tree using the `SWT.VIRTUAL` flag and an `ILazyTreeContentProvider` content provider.